# Having a function argument of type "Selector" in a Swift class will render the function unavailable to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, selector

When trying to use the Menu class below from my Objective-C code, I'm only able to access foobar (or any other function that does not have the Selector type in the argument list), while the addItemWithName function is unavailable (I have checked the autogenerated swift to objective-c file and the function is not listed in the Menu interface there). How can I make this work?

```
public class Menu : UIView {
    public func foobar() {
        // implementation
    }

    public func addItemWithName(itemName: String, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector?) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild project?

Comment: When creating new APIs, I would strongly advise not to use target & selector based callbacks. Better to pass a block/closure. For example, see `UIAlertController` and `UIAlertAction ` for the modern approach.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for the advice. I will see how I will do. In the project in question, the norm is to use target/action, so I will likely stick with that. But closures are of course interesting and I will gladly use them in similar situations in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem type isn't `Selector`, it's `Selector?`. You can't express `Optional<Selector>` in ObjC because `SEL` is not an object type.

Comment: Yes of course, I should have thought about that. Thanks! However, how do I make the selector nullable in a safe way? I want to be able to send in NULL occasionally (for special cases)...

Comment: A null selector is created with `Selector()` in Swift.

Comment: Yes, but will a NULL selector be accepted if the argument says Selector (without the questionmark)?

Comment: By the way, there is a way to express an optional selector in Objective-C: the __nullable keyword. The problem is that the translation from Swift fails to do this...

Comment: Yes, `Selector()` is legal to assign to a `Selector` type. I am surprised that `__nullable` works with `SEL` in ObjC; I suspect that's more coincidence than strong intent. `Selector()` is the same as `SEL(0)`, which happens to be the same representation as `nil` (and the same as the representation of `NULL` and also `0`). ObjC is built on C which doesn't have strong types, so 0 is 0 is 0 is 0. But in Swift, there are types, so not all zeros are the same.

Comment: Ok, great, now I feel that I understand the whole thing. Thanks again!

Comment: @RobNapier: "I am surprised that __nullable works with SEL in ObjC" It makes sense because `__nullable` works with all pointer types, and `SEL` is declared as a pointer type in Cocoa Objective-C.